# Is it possible to use Twitter and Facebook APIs on J2ME platform?

Tags: facebook, java-me, twitter

I googled and I can't find it is possible, someones said that j2me don't support REST communication or there are problems with login.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's definitely possible. There are plenty of [examples](http://code.google.com/p/java-twitter/) of [Twitter](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) and [Facebook](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_apps_written_in_Java) [Java](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/) code.

**Update:** I missed that the question was about J2ME. While it looks like none of the existing Twitter and Facebook libraries would work, you can make [HTTP connections in J2ME](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/network/), so REST queries should be possible.

Comment: Thanks, but none of that links seems to be j2me compliants

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I missed the J2ME part.