# How can I connect to Facebook/Twitter/etc. in a J2ME application?

Tags: java, facebook, java-me, oauth

(Note: I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202396/is-it-possible-to-use-twitter-and-facebook-apis-on-j2me-platform), but it only refers to REST, and not the new OAuth system.)

I would like to write a J2ME application (I have some basic experience of this) that connects to Facebook and retrieves some data, but I can't find an API. I understand that Facebook doesn't support WSDL (which, incidentally, I have never used) and Google's API doesn't support J2ME (generics, etc.).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a OAuth Library, I have yet to see a J2ME based OAuth2 library, Oauth1 can be found here
http://github.com/simonpk/j2me-oauth

Comment: Thanks - I was really looking to use OAuth 2.0, which I understand is much simpler to implement, but I'm not sure where to start!

Comment: Here is a question related to an OAuth2 Implementation for JAVA. If you found one, pls post it there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153022/is-there-a-oauth2-library-for-java-android-already

Comment: this might be helpful for you....http://blogs.shephertz.com/2013/05/13/doing-facebook-oauth-wit-nokia-s40-devices-using-app42-platform/