# Is there a OAuth2 library for Java / Android already?

Tags: java, android, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I don't want to code things that already exist...

Comment: I've written my own OAuth 1 and OAuth 2 library. I just see that draft 10 is out so I'll make changes accordingly.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your OAuth2 java library?

Comment: Sure, at the time when it was fully developed, it was up draft 5 specification. I'll update this and post it on either my blog or google projects. By when do you need this?

Comment: view my library here: http://code.google.com/p/joauth/downloads/detail?name=OAuth.jar&can=2&q=

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check mature and lightweight leeloo OAuth 2.0 Java library: http://leeloo.smartam.net/

It implements draft 10 of OAuth 2.0 specification and help you to build client, authorization and resource server.

It was not tested on an Android platform, but you are welcome to provide a feedback.

Comment: Leeloo is the former name of Apache Amber in the next post. However, as of this date, there are no stable distributions of Apache Amber, but there is a source tree.

Comment: leeloo worked for me, android 5.0, added the following lines to gradle:     compile 'net.smartam.leeloo:oauth2-common:0.1'
    compile 'net.smartam.leeloo:oauth2-client:0.1'

Comment: This is a dead link

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is a little old, but since google always directs me to this one when I search for an Android OAuth 2.0 library, I think I need to tell you about OAuth2Android:

Currently it supports Bearer-Tokens and MAC-Tokens based on the
specifications:

draft-ietf-oauth-v2-16
draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-06
draft-ietf-oauth-v2-http-mac-00

Other extensions are also possible and it will be updated.

You need at least Android Platform Version 2.3.3; API Level 10.
You can get it here:
https://github.com/Xotan/OAuth2Android
 or
git@github.com:Xotan/OAuth2Android.git

regards Christoph

Answer (score 3):

[OAuth 2](http://oauth.net/2/) is still in [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-10) stage (as of this writing, draft 10).

For now, Apache has an *incubator* project called [Apache Amber](http://wiki.apache.org/incubator/AmberProposal) which is:

> **"...a Java development framework mainly aimed to build OAuth-aware
> applications"**

Comment: Apache Amber has been moved to the attic. No new project should use that, since it's mostly a dead, unmaintained

Answer (score 3):

FYI, the Scribe java library is awesome - great docs, simple and dedicated to oauth.

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/getting-started

Comment: which version of OAuth does this library support? 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: It supports 1.0 and 2.0.  I've only used it for 1.0 however.

Comment: Last statement of the author of scribe-java: "OAuth 2.0 support is not going to get any more attention and may eventually be deprecated and dropped."

Answer (score 2):

The [google-oauth-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/) is written by Google, and supports OAuth 1.0 and 2.0 (draft 10)

Comment: It's OK for Java, but isn't it a bit "heavy" for Android apps? Almost ~6 MB is too much in my opinion.

Comment: I agree it's a bit heavyweight, but they recommend using ProGuard to strip unused code from your application. It's a good practice anyway, really.

Comment: It's good to know there is something like ProGuard. Thx for your response ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of OAuth libraries proposed by Twitter development wiki: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_libraries#java

Currently at least one of the mentioned libraries is qualified as mature by Twitter developers. I think we can trust their expertise in OAuth.

Comment: Those librarys seem to be OAuth1. If it's not like that, pls post the particular OAuth2 library.

Answer (score 0):

Leeloo worked great with Github.
https://bitbucket.org/smartproject/oauth-2.0/wiki/Home